# How to measure the memory used by C/C++/Java Program while during execution?

Tags: java, c++, c, memory, memory-management

I am trying to create a programming judge like [spoj.pl](http://spoj.pl). I have to measure the time and memory a C/C++/Java program is using. I want to set a maximum memory limit for the program that I wish to execute. Can you please suggest how I can do that.

Comment: There's a gigantic difference between measuring how much memory a program uses and setting how much it is allowed to use at most. At least in java there is. Also even the most basic research (single google search) would've found you the right commandline switch for that..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

System-, where-, how-, what-,...- dependent.

---

To limit, i.e.:

Linux command line: > `$ ulimit -v NNN && ./tha_prog`, `$ man ulimit`, `$ ulimit -a`.

Linux C coded: > `setrlimit()` linux.die: [setrlimit](http://linux.die.net/man/2/setrlimit), opengroup:[setrlimit](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/setrlimit.html)

Windows: `CreateJobObject`, [Job Objects](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms684161%28VS.85%29.aspx)

Then the question also becomes what to limit. Static vs dynamic libraries etc.

---

To profile:

Valgrind with callgrind, - and ie [kcachegrind](http://kcachegrind.sourceforge.net/html/Home.html), +++.

Answer (score 1):

In order to analyze time and memory consumption you can use callgrind:
http://valgrind.org/docs/manual/cl-manual.html

Answer (score 0):

On Windows you can use [jobs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684161%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), which are kernel objects that allow you to sandbox any process not currently in another job. You can apply all different types of restrictions, including maximum processing time and memory/working set restrictions.

There are a few steps
1. Call [`CreateJobObject`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682409%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to get a handle to the kernel object
2. Call [`SetInformationJobObject`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686216%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to set up your restrictions
3. Create a suspended process that you want to place restrictions on
4. Call [`AssignProcessToJobObject`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms681949%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) with the job and process handles
5. Resume the process's main thread by calling `ResumeThread`